# Disabling a button a second time isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a toolbar on my page with various buttons.  When ever one of those buttons is clicked, the button gets disabled using jQuery's prop('disabled', true) function and a subform is displayed on the page.

Within the subform is a cancel button.  Clicking the cancel button destroys the subform and re-enables the button in the toolbar using prop('disabled', false).  Up to this point, everything works fine.  However, as soon as I click on the same toolbar button again, it no longer gets disabled.

I've tried this using the jQuery prop function, attr, or simply .disabled = true.  Nothing seems to work if the button has already gone through a cycle of disable then enable.

Any thoughts?

Here's my disable/enable functions.

```
  /**
   * Disables form elements.
   */
  $.fn.disable = function(enableSiblings) {
    this.each(function() {
      // Disables a Bootstrap button and declaratively enables any sibling buttons
      var btn = $(this).hasClass('btn') ? this : $(this).parent('.btn').get(0);
      if(btn) {
        $(btn).prop('disabled', true);
        if(enableSiblings === undefined || enableSiblings) {
          $(btn).siblings('.btn').enable();
        }
      }

      // Disables a textarea
      if($(this).is('textarea')) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  };

  /**
   * Enables form elements.
   */
  $.fn.enable = function() {
    this.each(function() {
      // Enables a Bootstrap button
      var btn = $(this).hasClass('btn') ? this : $(this).parent('.btn').get(0);
      if(btn) {
        $(btn).prop('disabled', false);
      }

      // Enables a textarea
      if($(this).is('textarea')) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });
  };
```

My cancel event merely calls the enable function above when the cancel button is clicked.

Comment: Using a web inspector, do you see the `disabled` attribute being set on the html element itself?

Comment: On the first time around yes.  On the second time around, no.

Comment: Is the closing of the subform altering the DOM in anyway? I see some dom traversal in the function, it could break finding the button if the dom changes -  might be more useful for us if you can make a simple jsfiddle demo

Comment: Well, I created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D9AX7/1/ and removed some of the unnecessary stuff.  However in that process, it made it work the way I want it to.  Guess I'll have to review my code.